# Install Yeoman on C9.io

Tags: linux, cloud9-ide, yeoman

Has anyone tried to install [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) in the [Cloud9](http://c9.io) environment? If so how to do it?

I get this error on any yeoman command:

```
<FATAL> EACCES, permission denied '/var/lib/stickshift/' </FATAL>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so I played a little bit with Cloud9 and yeoman ;)

Seems like your error comes mainly from the fact that yeoman is trying to goes up the tree, looking for a Gruntfile.js ... Doing so it encounters an issue as the directory it tries to read are not accessible for the current user.

The first work-around is to create an empty Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = function (grunt) {
 // Project configuration.
 grunt.initConfig({});
 };
```

Then launching "yeoman init" will ask you the standard questions and at a given point will ask you if it can overwrite the Gruntfile, which you can answer positively ;)

Then if you launch a "yeoman server", you'll encounter another error, due to the port the server is willing to answer.

Add the following options to your Gruntfile.js:

```
  server: {
    port: process.env.PORT,
    host: process.env.IP
},
```

Note that you also need to have Compass installed (gem install compass).

Then launching "yeoman server' will launch the server and the needed task (ending with the watch task) ...

I didn't went further down the path though ;)

Hope this helps.
[image: cloud 9 yeoman screenshot]

Comment: This looks pretty close.  How do you access the server in the browser?

Comment: Mainly by targetting https://<workspacename>.<username>.c9.io (for example in my case http//test.sleeper.c9.io)

Comment: cool thanks!! in my case it fails when it runs the match task

Running "watch" task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Waiting...Fatal error: listen EACCES  

do you know what it could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this, was racking my brain on what the problem was. Changing the grunt server options to the ones above fired up my server perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I can install yeoman but after running install for generators, they don't work:
$ yo angular
Error angular

You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.

Tried a couple other generators, none work so not just an issue with angular.

Then found: 
[Why are my Yeoman generators installing in the wrong place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081125/why-are-my-yeoman-generators-installing-in-the-wrong-place)

Fixed it!

Comment: Can you tell me after doing `gulp serve`  and launching the preview which url should i put to view my changes?

Comment: how to view `localhost:3000` on c9.io ?