# Why are my Yeoman generators installing in the wrong place?

Tags: npm, yeoman

I have a problem with Yeoman generators. They install just fine if I run "npm install [generator-name] -g". However when I try to run "yo [generator-name] yeoman can't seem to find the generator. Neither is it listed among my other generators if I just run "yo". I've tried a bunch of generators and the result is always the same.

After a bit of bit of investigation I found that the downloaded generator is placed in

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

But my other generators  are placed in

```
/usr/local/lib/share/npm/lib/node_modules/
```

Here is an image of how it looks on my machine https://i.stack.imgur.com/InQcZ.png, I'm running OSX in case that matters. Looks like something is wrong to me - but I cannot figure it out.

Not sure if this helps, but brew doctor and $NODE_PATH return nothing while $PATH returns:

```
-bash: 
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:
/Users/marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:
/Users/marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:
/Users/marcus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:
/Users/marcus/.rvm/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

---

I tried what Eddie Monge Jr suggested and now my angular generator works fine. However when I installed another generator (chrome-extension) yeoman insists that it's not installed/found.

When I run **ls $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules** I get this:

```
bower                      generator-mocha
generator-angular          grunt-cli
generator-chrome-extension npm
generator-karma            yo
```

And **npm list -g** returns this (I cut out a lot of generic stuff)

```
/usr/local/lib
├─┬ bower@1.2.3
├─┬ generator-angular@0.4.0
│ └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.13.3
├─┬ generator-chrome-extension@0.2.3
│ └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.12.3
├─┬ generator-karma@0.5.0
│ └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.13.3
├─┬ generator-mocha@0.1.1
│ └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.10.5
├─┬ grunt-cli@0.1.9
├─┬ npm@1.3.5
└─┬ yo@1.0.0
```

The strange part for me is if I run **yo --help** I get a strange list of generators

```
[?] What would you like to do?
  [ ] Run the Angular generator
  [ ] Run the Foundation generator
  [ ] Run the H5bp generator
  [X] Run the Mocha generator
  [ ] Run the Webapp generator
  [ ] Run the Karma generator
  [ ] Update your generators
  [ ] Install a generator
  [ ] Find some help
  [ ] Get me out of here!
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I tried installing Yeoman on an Ubuntu precise32 vagrant vm. I ran into the same problem: Yeoman did not find the generators I installed, although there were no errors during the installation of these generators. Files were in place and permissions seemed alright.

The above solutions didn't work for me.

I ran

```
yo doctor
```

to see what was wrong, and as it turned out, the following was the problem:

```
[Yeoman Doctor] Uh oh, I found potential errors on your machine
---------------

[Error] NPM root value is not in your NODE_PATH
  [info]
    NODE_PATH = /usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
    NPM root  = /home/vagrant/npm/lib/node_modules

  [Fix] Append the NPM root value to your NODE_PATH variable
    Add this line to your .bashrc
      export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/vagrant/npm/lib/node_modules
    Or run this command
      echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/vagrant/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

The fix suggested by the Yeoman Doctor worked as advertised.

Comment: How did you run [Yeoman Doctor]? Can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I'll mark your reply as the answer since I'm quite sure that my issue was similar. I removed NPM and updated Node.JS to the latest version. I then installed NPM again using this SH script [link](https://npmjs.org/install.sh). The script found and removed a couple of weird NPM paths and now it's up and running properly again. Cheers!

Comment: to run yeoman doctor, you need to `locate doctor.js` (with me, it was a path ending in `.../yo/scripts/doctor.js` and just run it with node. Also, what finally helped me to run yo was to start over with `npm cache clean` in between (after `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo`, before reinstalling yo).

Answer (score 24):

I hit this issue and I'm hoping it will help someone.
I believe upgrading NPM caused this initial issue for me.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Was the location of a lot of my modules in the past. Since upgrading node at some point, the directory became

```
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules
```

When I would run new installations such as:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

I since I run `grunt` from the command line it wouldn't 'find' it (that's because it wasn't in my new node_modules dir). I set up this up in my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Now I am pointing to the *new* `node_modules` directory
So all the new npm modules I install find the right location: /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules

But not `yo`

I ran a `which yo` and my path was

```
/usr/local/bin/yo
```

This binary was pointing to the *OLD* `node_modules` installation @

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

My solution was to do this

```
rm /usr/local/bin/yo
npm remove -g yo
```

The old reference to `yo` is gone for keeps, now I can do

```
npm install -g yo
```

This will add it to the new `node_modules` location

```
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules
```

and now the new 'yo' references the proper node_modules installation base

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

then we can see yo is referenced from the proper spot

```
which yo
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/yo
```

all future generators will be placed in the proper `node_modules` directory and `yo` will be able to find them without a problem!

Comment: Sounds pretty much like the error I had. I did try **npm remove -g yo** a couple of times without success however. What I didn't do was to run **rm /usr/local/bin/yo**, I'm not sure if that would have solved made any difference though. But thanks!

Comment: This made it for me! I also added a symlink to the bash_profile to make `yo` work. The following line: `PATH=${PATH}:~/.node/bin` and don't forget to restart the prompt for the change to take action.

Answer (score 7):

I uninstalled yeoman entirely, then re-installed it

```
npm remove -g yo
npm install -g yo
```

This fixed my problem with missing angular generators.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your npm may be out of whack. Check where things are installed:
    npm config get prefix
Is that where you expected the packages to install? Is that where they are currently installed?

To list whats in there:

```
ls $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
```

That will list out the globally installed npm packages.

```
npm list -g
```

Will list the currently installed things. Make sure yo and the generators are listed at the top level.

To remove the yo stuff and start over:

```
npm remove -g yo generator-* yeoman-generator
npm install -g yo generator-angular
```

That should fix things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't have access to my work computer right now but I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm my angular generator now works, I've tried both the chrome-extension and backbone generator without luck however - Yeoman can't seem to find it. I've updated my question above.

Comment: yep, since I removed the `yo generator` stuff  I can `npm update` && `npm -g update` without warnings again.  I wanted to checkout the yeoman workflow.