# Yeoman can't recognize a generator that was installed globally

Tags: npm, yeoman

I ran `sudo npm install -g generator-flask` and it was saved. I was able to confirm by running `npm list-g`.

I then run `yo flask`. Thinking that this was going to work, I instead get an error message:

```
Error flask

You don't seem to have a generator with the name flask installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 22 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

I do as it tells me by running `yo --help` and discover that the flask generator is not there.

I try this with `sudo npm install -g generator-angular-flask` and the problem is recreated with Angular Flask. I'm assuming this is going to happen for all the generators which is why I've titled it as Yeoman not recognizing new npm installs.

Does anyone know why this has happened?

Answer (score 19):

A workaround, but does solve the problem:

```
npm link generator-angular-flask
```

(as does just installing the module locally)

Comment: so weird! this worked but I still don't get what's wrong with my setup. I'm using nvm and I think that may play a role. Also this isn't good enough because the generator I'm using requires an empty directory. But thanks.

Comment: I think the problem you're experiencing is with npm path. That's where mine was happening. I forget how I fixed it, but I had to ask someone to help me.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081125/why-are-my-yeoman-generators-installing-in-the-wrong-place?rq=1) answer might be able to help you out. This was my issue overall.

Answer (score 18):

Usually it is a $NODE_PATH issue, but rather then guessing, run:

```
yo doctor
```

and follow the instructions!

Comment: Didn't know about the doctor command. Fantastic. It tells you exactly what's wrong and what to do. Thanks. Up-voted.

Comment: oh my goodness that is the best thing ever. i wish more command line applications had something like `yo doctor`.

Answer (score 6):

Node path is the issue.
To setup path:

```
export NODE_PATH=$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/
```

In my case node is in HOME directory.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue.  Basically Yeoman was showing No installed generators, even if I fired up yeoman and installed the generator again still no luck to run it.

I typed `yo doctor` and did the changes it recommends, but still no luck...

I then ran

```
export NODE_PATH=$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/
```

Then I fired up Yeoman and still no luck.

I then decide run `yo doctor` again and voila! New errors.  I then saw the final recommendation by the yo doctor so I decide to run it:

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/Users/slickstyles/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

After I type `yo` and guess what I see? All my installed yeoman generators showing and working marvelously.

Comment: Marvelous. Thanks.

Comment: boom! Thanx a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
yo doctor
```

and you will not something like:

```
npm root value is not in your NODE_PATH                                                                                                                                                                     

[Info]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  NODE_PATH = /home/action/.node/lib/node_modules/                                                                                                                                                          
  npm root  = /home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules                                                                                                                                                          

[Fix] Append the npm root value to your NODE_PATH variable                                                                                                                                                  
Add this line to your .bashrc                                                                                                                                                                               
    export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules                                                                                                                                        
  Or run this command                                                                                                                                                                                       
    echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

and try again:

```
npm install -g generator-webapp
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `NODE_PATH` set. To set it open a terminal and type (assuming you have node under `/opt/node/` and use `bash` shell)

```
echo "export NODE_PATH=/opt/node:/opt/node/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

Once done, run `yo doctor`. If all is ok, run `yo` to see your installed generators.