# "You don't seem to have a generator with the name jhipster installed."

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I have gone through the steps as listed on http://jhipster.github.io/installation/ without any errors.

Then, I try the simple steps to get started that are on the jhipster home page, being:

> Install JHipster npm install -g generator-jhipster
>
> Create a new directory and go into it mkdir myApp && cd myApp Run
>
> JHipster and follow instructions on screen yo jhipster

However, when I run the last instruction, I get the following error:

```
yo jhipster
Error jhipster 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name jhipster installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: did the `npm install -g generator-jhipster` command run without errors?

Comment: There are no errors when running this line. The last output is: npm WARN engine word-wrap@1.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.8"} (current: {"node":"6.0.0-pre","npm":"3.3.12"})
/usr/local/lib
└── generator-jhipster@2.27.0

Comment: you might wanna check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118807/yeoman-cant-recognize-a-generator-that-was-installed-globally

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ubuntu, surely you have installed jhipster using sudo privileges...
So you have to do `sudo chown -R yourUser:yourGroup /usr/lib/node_modules && npm install -g generator-jhipster` as normal user...
After that, you can generate your project

Comment: What do you mean  `yourGroup` ?