# Unable to create a new angular app with Yeoman

Tags: angularjs

I am using node `v4.2.4` I installed [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generator and tried creating my Angular app as follows

```
yo angular myApp
```

I am getting the following error

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular:common:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 15 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

Upon running `yo --help` I get the following result

```
Available Generators:
  angular
    common
    constant
    controller
    decorator
    directive
    factory
    filter
    main
    provider
    route
    service
    value
    view
  karma
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493299/yeoman-angular-generator-install-runs-but-generator-doesnt-appear-in-generator).

Comment: It is an open issue [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1239). Unfortunately there is no fix yet.

Comment: As stated there's no fix yet. I suggest going with other generators such as angular-fullstack or gulp-angular.