# -bash: yo: command not found

Tags: npm, yeoman

Like a lot of people I am also having issues with Yeoman.
Error `-bash: yo: command not found` in OSx.

I tried adding `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH` on my .bash_profile as suggested by some folks and still same error.

I've lost 2 hours of my productivity trying to fix Yeoman bugs and still nothing.

Does anyone know any good solution that fixes the `-bash: yo: command not found` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this.

First I had to uninstall and install yo again:

```
npm remove -g yo
npm install -g yo
```

I also added a symlink to the bash_profile to make yo work. The following line: `PATH=${PATH}:~/.node/bin` After that restart the prompt for the change to take action.

Please check this for more references: [Why are my Yeoman generators installing in the wrong place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081125/why-are-my-yeoman-generators-installing-in-the-wrong-place?rq=1)

Answer (score 13):

I found that for recent versions of npm, all node packages are installed in the `~/npm/bin/` directory.

So add those lines to your `$PATH` in the `.profile` file :

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm/bin
```

Then do :

```
source ~/.profile
yo -v
```

Comment: in my case I added "export PATH=$PATH:~/npm/bin" to my .bashrc , work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try to add an symbolic-link (ln -s) into the /sbin -directory.
like:

```
ln -s /sbin/ /usr/local/share/npm/bin/yo
```

Comment: Thanks for replying back mate. This is what I am getting:

ln: /usr/local/share/npm/bin/yo: No such file or directory

Comment: Is there an /usr/local/share/npm/sbin directory ? Look if there is an file named "yo" and if so try to softlink this file.

Comment: Thanks mate. I did what you suggested followed by the reinstallation of yo and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work :)

```
sudo `yo angular2-ts [appname]`
```

where `[appname]` is the name of your app (without the []) :)

Answer (score 0):

just give access for the user to read write execute in the folder webapp

```
sudo chmod 777 webapp
cd webapp
yo angular [appname]
```